# How to use the IXAudio2Voice::SetChannelVolume function

Tags: audio, xaudio2

I am wondering how to use the `IXAudio2Voice::SetChannelVolume` function. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee418585.aspx) tells me to pass the number of channels for the first parameter. But which "number of channels" do I need and how can I get that value? Do I have to use the number of input channels which can be retrieved from the `GetVoiceDetails`-function (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.ixaudio2voice.ixaudio2voice.getvoicedetails%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))?

Answer (score 1):

It is expecting the number of channels in the voice.

This should be the same as the channel count when the voice was created, the value of nChannels in the WAVEFORMATEX struct.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390970(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390970%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
IXAudio2SourceVoice* pSourceVoice;
if( FAILED(hr = pXAudio2->CreateSourceVoice( &pSourceVoice, (WAVEFORMATEX*)&wfx ) ) ) return hr;
```

wfx.nChannels is the channel count for the voice

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415828(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415828%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! But how can I get the number of channels from the voice? Isn't there a method which returns the number of channels? can i retrieve it from the `GetVoiceDetails`-function?